# Books on numerical method in solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

I am searching for a reference book that details numerical methods for solving differential equations, their rate (order) of convergence,  their cost, and if possible some applications.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: solving partial differential equations.

Comment: Ordinary differential equations? Partial differential equations?

Comment: Although your question is not specific on ODEs vs. PDEs, look into 1. Numerical Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations 3rd Edition
by J. C. Butcher, 2. Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I: Nonstiff Problems by Ernst Hairer,‎ Syvert P. Nørsett,‎ Gerhard Wanner, 3. Solving Ordinary Differential Equations II: Stiff and Differential-Algebraic Problems. There are **many** others, but those are worth a look.

Comment: You should have been explicit upfront. Solving ODEs and PDEs are completely different matters.

Comment: @Nizar: I am not as familiar with PDEs, but you might want to peruse the books given [*Google*](https://www.google.com/search?q=best+numerical+analysis+books+pdes&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS750US750&oq=best+numerical+analysis+books+pdes&aqs=chrome..69i57.6855j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)